# Remove event listener that was created inside of a function? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-listener

I'm trying to remove an event listener that was created inside of a function, but for some reason, it isn't working. It works fine if I take it out of the function. Example below:

```
<body>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
<button type='submit' onclick='rel()'>RemoveEventListener</button>

<script>
function Mouse() {
    myDiv.addEventListener('click', cK);
    function cK() {
        alert('You've clicked on myDiv!');
    }
}
function rel() {
    myDiv.removeEventListener('click', cK);
}
Mouse();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: How do you get reference to your `myDiv` component? Do you use same ref for removing?

Comment: I have a global variable that contains it but I forgot to copy it

Comment: @VadimB Also with `id='myDiv'` corresponding HTMLElement gets exposed as global variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `ck` is defined inside of `Mouse` it's not available in `rel`. Move it outside:

```
function cK() {
    alert('You\'ve clicked on myDiv!');
}
function Mouse() {
    myDiv.addEventListener('click', cK);
}
function rel() {
    myDiv.removeEventListener('click', cK);
}
```

Comment: Please also see VadimB's comment on question

Comment: Can the remove function, called before adding the event listener, cause issues?